# ZF3 zend-mvc-skeleton internationalization not working

Tags: zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework3, zf3

I'm trying to evaluate if it's already the right time to start moving to ZF3 (or keep developing my application with ZF2). Therefore, I installed the mvc-skeleton application and walked through the MVC tutorial ([here](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/overview/)) which worked perfectly until I got to the internationalization part.

I installed the components (i.e. zend-i18n and zend-mvc-i18n component), created the translation files (i.e. en_US.mo and en_US.po) and copied them into my `module/Application/language/` folder and added the configuration in the application configuration file.

```
// in a module's module.config.php:
'translator' => [
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => [
        [
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ],
    ],
],
```

And of course, added the text to translate in the layout.phtml file

```
<p>&copy; 2016 by Examples Ltd. <?= $this->translate('All rights reserved') ?></p>
```

However, for some reason it's not working

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException    

File:
my_install_path/zend-mvc-skeleton-application/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php:133

Message:
A plugin by the name "translate" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\View\HelperPluginManager

Stack trace:
#0 /my-own-install-path/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(373): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('translate', NULL)
#1 /my-own-install-path/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(391): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->plugin('translate')
#2 /my-own-install-path/module/Application/view/application/index/index.phtml(1): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->__call('translate', Array)
#3 /my-own-install-path/module/Application/view/application/index/index.phtml(1): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->translate('Dr Job')
#4 /my-own-install-path/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(502): include('/Applications/M...')
#5 /my-own-install-path/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php(207): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#6 /my-own-install-path/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php(236): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#7 /my-own-install-path/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php(200): Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#8 /my-own-install-path/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(105): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#9 /my-own-install-path/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(271): Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 /my-own-install-path/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(143): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 /my-own-install-path/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(369): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#12 /my-own-install-path/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(348): Zend\Mvc\Application->completeRequest(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#13 /my-own-install-path/public/index.php(43): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#14 {main}
```

My question is simple. Did you succeed in this or do you have any idea of what's wrong with it? Any help will be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to config translator/I18n on controller or via controller plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like it can't find the translate view helper.  Try adding this in your config file:

```
'view_helpers' => [
    'invokables' => [
        'translate' => \Zend\I18n\View\Helper\Translate::class
    ]
]
```

I also found I needed to register the service:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        \Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface::class => \Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory::class,
    ]
]
```

Comment: Great, the view_helpers array did the job.

Comment: How to do the same to work translator on controller?

Comment: First inject the translate view helper into the controller using a factory (code: `$serviceManager->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('translate')`).

Then in the controller use the translator's `__invoke` method i.e. `$translatedString = $translateHelper("Here is a string")`.

Answer (score 13):

I got the "plain vanilla" solution from samsonasik [here](https://github.com/zendframework/tutorials/issues). The solution is to require:

```
$ composer require zendframework/zend-mvc-i18n
```

then register as module:

```
'modules' => [
     'Zend\I18n',
     'Zend\Mvc\I18n',
     // ...
],
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Additionally, if you are using zend-component-installer, it should *ask* you if you want to install these modules, and then do it for you. If you are not using zend-component-installer yet, add it to your application via `composer require zendframework/zend-component-installer`, as it automates this.

Comment: this is the correct answer, an installer does not include 'Zend\I18n' to the array of modules, only 'Zend\Mvc\I18n', so its config is not included to the application initially

Answer (score 0):

It work me with this configuration:

```
'translator' => [
    'locale' => 'cs_CZ',
    'translation_file_patterns' => [
        [
            'type' => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => APPLICATION_MODULE_ROOT . '/language',
            'pattern' => '%s.mo',
        ],
    ],
],
```

With which modules you have installed zf3? 
zend-servicemanager do you have installed?

Comment: The modules installed are:
    'Zend\Mvc\I18n',
    'Zend\Log',
    'Zend\Form',
    'Zend\Db',
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'Application'