# How to get translator inside controller plugin on ZF3

Tags: zend-framework3, zend-controller-plugin

I want to create a plugin to use zend-i18n/translate on controller. On zf2 I have a controller plugin that does this for me, but on zf3 I could not get this to work. How can I use zend-i18n inside a controller or via controller plugin with zf3?

==========
I just found what I need here on zf doc: https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-mvc-i18n/services/#mvctranslator-and-translatorfactory

if you already have config the translator as factory on your module.config.php, you can inject on your controller plugin.

Comment: Did you look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38293988/zf3-zend-mvc-skeleton-internationalization-not-working

Comment: Thanks for reply, but translate on view I already config and is working fine, I need translate on controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can virtually do the same as [the answer that @hkulekci referred to in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38293988/1697459).

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        \Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface::class => \Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory::class,
    ]
]
```

and

```
'controller_plugins' => [
    'invokables' => [
        'translate' => \Zend\I18n\View\Helper\Translate::class
    ]
]
```

After that you can get the translate plugin like in your controller action methods like this:

```
public someAction(){
    $translator = $this->translate;
}
```

Check the [Zend Framework documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html) or [this Zend Framework blog](http://www.masterzendframework.com/servicemanager/accessing-servicemanager-services-controller-plugins/) for more details on the controller plugin manager.

Comment: Hi, I create a plugin called translate, and inject into the serviceManager, then inside the plugin I get the global MvcTranslator, and work fine. but thanks. One question is that right on your configuration using the View\Helper\Translate::class as plugin?

Answer (score 2):

For translate in model and controller, I did this in my module.config.php

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        \Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator::class => \Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

Then from my controller or model which has serviceContainer initialised I do:

```
$this->myVar = $serviceContainer->get(\Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator::class);
```

Then I can access it by doing

```
$this->myVar->translate('lorem ipsum');
```